# How can energy of petrol be compared to electricity?

Tags: energy, power, efficient-energy-use

When driving my car, which is powered by an electrical engine, I'm consuming between 10 and 17 kWh per 100 km (measured at the charging outlet).

The car I had before consumed between 5 and 8 litres of petrol/gas (95 octane) for 100 km.

Independently of the cost and energy necessary for storage, creation and transportation, how can these two units be compared or can't they? What is the equivalent of 1 l of petrol in kWh?

Also, do not hesitate to correct my question (if possible) if the terminology is not appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, these numbers can be compared. You can find a [list with the required data on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Energy_densities_of_common_energy_storage_materials). According to that table 1l of gasoline can provide 9.5 kWh of chemically stored energy. If you compare this to your electric energy demand you will realize that the energy conversion efficiency of a combustion engine is rather limited.

Comment: If your comparison is strictly cost based, calculate the dollars/km for gasoline, and compare it to the dollars/km that you are paying for electricity (which is billed in kW-hr).

Comment: Thus we would need at least 9.5 kWh (in a perfect system, which does not exist) to create 1 l of (synthetic) petrol.